# Nifi: Flow content (dynamic json format) to csv

Tags: json, apache, csv, apache-nifi, apache-minifi

I have case: in flow content is **always json format** and **the data inside json always change (both kyes and values)**. Is this possible to convert this **flow content to csv**?

**Please note that, keys in json are always change.**

Many thanks,

Comment: Yes, You can use this link https://community.hortonworks.com/questions/63995/convert-json-to-csv-using-nifi.html and 

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49145832/convert-json-to-csv-in-nifi

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Convert JSON to CSV in nifi](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49145832/convert-json-to-csv-in-nifi)

Comment: hi, in this example they specify the keys in json. in my case, the keys in json are always changes, so I cant apply it

Comment: Can you give more details? Like will the csv  headers remain the same or are they also dynamic ? And please give a specific example

Answer (score 0):

To achieve this usecase we need to generate avro schema **dynamically** for each **json record** first then **convert to AVRO** finally **convert AVRO to CSV**

***Flow:***
[image]

```
1.SplitJson //split the array of json records into individual records

2.InferAvroSchema //infer the avro schema based on Json record and store in attribute

3.ConvertJSONToAvro //convert each json record into Avro data file

4.ConvertRecord //read the avro data file dynamically and convert into CSV format

5.MergeContent (or) MergeRecord processor //to merge the splitted flowfiles into one flowfile based on defragment strategy.
```

Save [this](https://github.com/shureddy/Templates/blob/Dynamic_convertion_from_json_to_csv/dynamic.xml) xml and **upload to your nifi instance** and change as per your requirements.

Comment: Thank you so much for your suggestion, that is so useful :). 

In the case, my json are array as: 
[{"a":"IboECKV", "b":"2018-09-14 21:05:02.000Z", "c":"2132a4"}, 
{"a":"IboECKV", "b_a2":"2018-09-14 21:05:02.000Z_b2", "c":"2132a4_c2"}] 

the same keys name for each record, Is there any way to convert them to AVRO without split json?????

Comment: @ThuyLe, It's not possible because you are having **different keys(b,b_a2) for two json records**, **InferAvroSchema** processor works only on **one record** at a time. So to convert into CSV format you have to split the json then dynamically generate schema for **each record** then convert to CSV format dynamically.

Comment: hi @shu, sorry the right data is [{"a":"IboECKV", "b":"2018-09-14 21:05:02.000Z", "c":"2132a4"}, {"a":"IboECKV_a2", "b":"2018-09-14 21:05:02.000Z", "c":"2132a4_c2"}]

Comment: Hi @Shu, in  some cases we have json array with 100M rows, we split json convert it to avro then merger again, it will be take time, I understand that InferAvroSchema processor works only on one record at a time, does Nifi have other processor to do that?

Comment: @ThuyLe, NiFi supports dynamic read of schema for **CSV,Avro** formats. But coming to **Json** format this is not yet possible to read dynamically on **array of json records**. So that is the reason why need to split the json and convert to Avro.